# Excel VBA to click submit javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, cdata, vba

I cannot figure out how to fire event to enter data into input box.  There appears to be no id name associated with javascript in which to click.  I wonder if it is necessary to simulate a Submit of the form.  But there is no html submit and instead there is a javascript submit section.  How does VBA fire the submit?

```
<form method="post" action="AddDeductions?formId=ccf28bb7-e24a-46f2-ae7e-a7016521654c&amp;locationCd=001&amp;regionCode=MAR&amp;busClass=017" id="EasyTax">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="1_Taxes_ExpandState" id="1_Taxes_ExpandState" value="unnnnnunnunnnnununnunnnnnnunnnnnunnnnunnn" />
<input type="hidden" name="1_Taxes_SelectedNode" id="1_Taxes_SelectedNode" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

   <table class="webGrid" data-swhgajax="true" data-swhgcontainer="gridContent" data-swhgcallback="gridChangeCallBack">
<tr class="alt">
  <td class="amount"><span> <span id="spanDeduction_534"></span> 
  <input class="DeductionAmt" id="Deduction_534" maxlength="13" name="Deduction_534" placeholder="0.00" style="text-align: right;" type="text" value="0.00" />
  <label id="forTxtxAmt" for="deduction_534" hidden="hidden">TPT Tax</label></span></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['EasyTax'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.EasyTax;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

The following VBA code does not work.  The 99 is displayed but "not submitted" in the input box.

```
Set xcc = IE.document.getElementById("Deduction_534")
Set evt = IE.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents") 
evt.initEvent "change", False, True
xcc.Focus 'this works and the input box is focused
xcc.click 'not sure if this works as I don't see the cursor placed on the box
xcc.Value = 99 'this shows up in input box
xcc.dispatchEvent evt 'does nothing
ie.document.forms("EasyTax").submit 'submit action occurs but no data is submitted
```

1) Is there any way to fire an event to submit the 99?

2) How do I run the javascript code in the CDATA section using VBA to submit?